# Term for reference to ambient surroundings when creating a work?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term in English (or borrowed from other languages) that describes the moment wherein an author mentions what is happening whilst creating the work one is reading?

As an example, consider the following verse in Bob Dylan's *Blind Willie McTell*:

***I’m gazing out the window
 
Of the St. James Hotel***
And I know no one can sing the blues
Like Blind Willie McTell

My interpretation is that he is gazing out the window *when writing the lyric*: an intimate moment that bring us even closer, and may describe the inspiration.

Personally, I find that moment absolutely chilling. Is there a name for it?

Comment: In theater, television, and cinema, this is *breaking the fourth wall*, especially when directed towards the audience. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall I don't think the same phrase would apply to writing, though.

Comment: That is a brilliant observation, Jim. I find those moments intriguing as well.

Comment: The melody is loosely based on the (brilliant) New Orleans standard "St. James Infirmary", so I definitely see these [lyrics](http://www.bobdylan.com/songs/blind-willie-mctell) as a tip-of-the-hat.

Answer (score 3):

It can be called [*authorial intrusion*](http://literary-devices.com/content/authorial-intrusion) or *narrative intrusion*, although these terms describe a more general literary device, where the author interrupts the story to say something directly to the reader. I don't know any special terminology for the more specific case where the author says something about what is happening while they are writing.

Comment: I recently watched the somewhat disturbing [Funny Games](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808279/). Well into the movie there are a couple of brief moments where an character briefly, wordlessly, and unexpectedly acknowledges the camera/audience by [eye] movement. It's like being dragged onto the stage in the middle of a play!